# Hyper Fabric [fabric-sdk-go] Error: CONNECTION_FAILED. Description: dialing connection timed out

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

when I try to Create a request (proposal) and send it by using [Execute](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/channel#Client.Execute),

```
    ctxCh := sdk.ChannelContext("mychannel", fabsdk.WithUser("user1"))
    chClient, err := channel.New(ctxCh)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error from New channel", err)
    }

    req := channel.Request{
        ChaincodeID: "fabcar",
        Fcn:         "createCar",
        Args:        [][]byte{[]byte("CAR10"), []byte("Honda"), []byte("Accord"), []byte("Black"), []byte("Tom")},
    }
    resp, err := chClient.Execute(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error from Execute =", err)
    }
```

I get this error:

> calling orderer 'orderer.example.com:7050' failed: Orderer Client
>   Status Code: (2) CONNECTION_FAILED. Description: dialing connection
>   timed out [orderer.example.com:7050]

my config.yaml

```
channels:
  # name of the channel
  mychannel:
    orderers:
      - orderer.example.com

orderers:
  orderer.example.com:
    url: grpc://localhost:7050

    # these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
    # they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com

    tlsCACerts:
      # Certificate location absolute path
      path: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I think Execute function trying to connect with orderer service 'orderer.example.com:7050', and can't find it, 
If I'm right, then how I can change orderer.example.com:7050 to grpc://localhost:7050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [rocketchat](https://chat.hyperledger.org), 
to slove this problem add to config.yaml

```
entityMatchers:
 orderer:
   - pattern: (\w+).example.(\w+)
     urlSubstitutionExp: grpc://localhost:7050
     sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer.example.com
     mappedHost: orderer.example.com
```

to map `grpc://localhost:7050` to `orderer.example.com`